# show enum as radio button in gsp

Tags: grails

In my domain class, i have one enum:-

```
class Product{
  Type type
  enum Type{
    MEDICINE, NON_MEDICINE
  }
}
```

By generating default view, this shows as a dropdown in create.gsp page. My requirement is to show it as a radio group in create page from where i can select any one of the two values by clicking on radio button. can anyone provide some help. thnks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
<g:radioGroup name="type"
                  values="${test.Product$Type?.values()}"
                  labels="${test.Product$Type.values()*.name()}"
                  value="${productInstance?.type?.name()}">
  ${it.radio} <g:message code="${it.label}" />&nbsp;
</g:radioGroup>
```

That should replace the current `g:select` in `grails-app/views/product/_form.gsp`

Comment: Your version is better, it uses real values from original enum :)

Comment: sorry but what is test in values and labels?

Comment: That's the package I put my Product class into when I was testing this... You're Product class will be in a different package, so obviously you'll need to change this...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<g:radioGroup name="type" values="${['MEDICINE', 'NON_MEDICINE']}" value="${currentInstance.type}" labels="${['Medicine', 'Non medicine']}">
<span>${it.label} - ${it.radio}</span>
</g:radioGroup>
```